# How to remove information in a column

Tags: r, regex, gsub

How can I delete this unnecessary information on the picture below

[image]

I`ve tried to split the column into to columns, also used the gsub function. Unsuccessfully. How can I write, so R will understand me, and remove "[...:ign].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you want to remove all text between brackets (and the brackets themselves), you can try: `gsub("\\[[^[]*]", "", df$v2)` where `df` is your data.frame, and `v2` is your column name...you can remove extra whitespace with `trimws`...if you need additional help, please clarify your above question further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the pattern `[...:ign]` with `"\\[.*:ign\\]"` and then replace it with an empty string using `sub()`.

```
str <- c("szukajdzie [szukajdzie:ign]",
"chamajde [chamajde:ign]",
"delajda [delajda:ign]")

sub(pattern = "\\[.*:ign\\]", replacement = "", str)
# [1] "szukajdzie " "chamajde "   "delajda "
```

I am not totally sure if you wanted to keep the space between your strings, so if you want to delete this aswell, just prefix your pattern with a space, like shown below:

```
sub(pattern = " \\[.*:ign\\]", replacement = "", str)
# [1] "szukajdzie" "chamajde"   "delajda"
```